# GTK equivalent to BackgroundWorker (MonoDevelop)

Tags: c#, .net, mono, cross-platform, monodevelop

What is the GTK equivalent to BackgroundWorker in Mono?

I've tried the following website: http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Thread_Management, but there doesn't seem to be any such thing as DispatchService. I need to update the GUI asynchronously at given intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLib.Timeout - Answered by mhutch on IRC.